# How to augment 3rd party modules with extra functions when using Typescript?

Tags: typescript, fp-ts

I have imported a module into the utility library I'm working on with the intent of augmenting and re-exporting it:

```
import * as ITE from "fp-ts/lib/TaskEither";

const foo = () => "foo";

export const TE = {
    ...ITE,
    foo
};
```

This works really well as I can import both the things that are in `ITE` and `foo` from my other modules. The problem is that the imported module (`ITE`) also declares an interface (`TaskEither`) that somehow doesn't get into the export so when I import `TE` elsewhere I can't see `TE.TaskEither`.

This is a bit unexpected because before doing this augmentation I was exporting the whole module like this:

```
export * as TE from "fp-ts/lib/TaskEither";
```

to enable VS Code to automatically import `TE` for me. What am I doing wrong with my current `export`? Is there a way to export not only the `const`s from `ITE`, but also the missing `interface`?

If I just re-add

```
export * as TE from "fp-ts/lib/TaskEither";
```

It fails as it conflicts with my local declaration of `TE`.

Comment: doesn't simple `export * from "fp-ts/lib/TaskEither";` in your re-export module work? I.e. without TE, since you are naming it in your main module anyway. Export items separately that is (prefix the foo const with export)

Comment: The whole point is to have `TE` because it helps with VS Code auto-importing (eg: when I type `TE` it will automatically give me the option to import `TE.` So i need it to be an actual object. The only problem is that the `interface` is not exported when I re-export my imports.

Comment: I see. Maybe you could provide a complete example (like, all 3 files, full source) to be able to easily reproduce.

Comment: This example can be used to fully reproduce the code. I literally have no more code.

Comment: I mean, minimal example. Anyway. I don't think you can have an "interface" as a member of an object. In your expeort, you are building an object with fields. One of them is another const you grab using expansion (... syntax), but the interface is not picked up, as an object may contain only fields, not type definitions?

Comment: I already figured it out. You have to use a `namespace` and within it redeclare the `interface` as a `type` of the same name.

Comment: Could you share the solution here?

Answer (score 0):

Typescript allows exporting a `namespace` with the same name (with declaration merging), so the solution is to add a `type` with the same name to the namespace in question:

```
import * as ITE from "fp-ts/lib/TaskEither";

const foo = () => "foo";

export const TE = {
    ...ITE,
    foo
};

export namespace TE {
    export type TaskEither<E, A> = ITE.TaskEither<E, A>;
}
```